# Download of xcode is not for lion

Tags: xcode, macos, version, osx-lion

I found xcode in mac app store for download. Unfortunately, it states my version (lion) is not new enough to download. So, where do I find an older version of xcode from apple?

The Command line version would be best.
 Where do I find a version of Xcode for osx lion from apple?
Where do I find the command line version of Xcode?
Must I install Xcode from some other place than apple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple have a section in the iOS developer site where you can download all past and present applications and tools. I believe for Lion OSX upto XCODE 4.6.3 is compatible.

[Developers site](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) (P.S you may need to login to download the content)

Comment: I have an appleId. Do I need to be part of mac developer program as well ($99)? I can not get to that site with current AppleId.

Comment: Only the most recent XCode version is available for non developers. Other older version will need either a iOS or Mac Developer program